# How can I insert a trademark symbol (TM) in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, symbols

How do I place a trademark symbol or "TM" in a `UITextView`?

Answer (score 9):

It is Unicode character U+2122: ™

Comment: What if i need it for french? is there a method to get that locale?

Answer (score 9):

You can also just copy and paste it- ™

Comment: I just copy and Paste it in UILabel in Swift 4.2

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to just type it, The keycode is option-2 on os x.

Answer (score 2):

To get "TM" symbol into a string, for instance, you'd write the string like this:

```
let stringphrase: String = "CopyPasta \u{2122} is the name of our new company"
```

Forward Slash '\': indicates that what comes after isn't to be read literally as a character.
The small 'u': short for unicode
The squiggly brackets '{}': What's inside is code, in this case it's the unicode identifer '2122; for the TM (trademark) symbol.

COPYRIGHT Unicode = 00A9
(those are zeroes not capital 'O')